# Measuring timing and delay in TCP connections in a C Program

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, high-availability

Summary: how do I time the events that happen over the network in a C program (or are their existing utilities to do the same)?

Detail: I am experimenting with High Availability on various levels and wanted to explore TCP as a possible way of ensuring rapid failover in the event of failures. To be a bit more precise, I want to see if it can detect failures in the orders of a few milliseconds (either out of the box or under certain conditions). Also, to explore the delays in using a Heartbeat on top of either TCP/UDP or some other OSI Layer (maybe the link layer) in a cluster.

So, is there a way of quantifying these delays in measurable units, like - using `clock()` in user-space code - from which I might get better insights into the process?

Comment: Have you tried using Wireshark to look at your packet times?

Comment: No. Let me think aloud. I make a server and client application (on the same host for now) and connect the client to the server, use wireshark to capture traces. Then, I kill the server. Now, what do I look at in the traces? I want to measure the reaction time of the kernel to client chain. How exactly would you suggest doing this?